# Django 'ImageFileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save this Image to the db with a ForeignKey attached also, so I can look it up later.

When trying to save it , I just get this error

```
'ImageFileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Models.py

```
class Usertasks(models.Model):
    TaskID = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    TaskStatus = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="missing")

class TaskImages(models.Model):
    UserTasks = models.ForeignKey(Usertasks, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
def task_info(request, taskid):
    task = Usertasks.objects.get(TaskID=taskid)
    files = os.listdir(task.OutputPath)
    fullpath = task.OutputPath
    print(files)
    for img in files:
        imagepath = fullpath + "/" + img
        with open(imagepath, 'rb') as f: 
            data = File(f)
            TaskImages.image.save(img, data, True, UserTasks=task)
    return render(request, 'dashboard/task.html', {'path':fullpath, 'image':files})
```

Comment: FileDescriptor like objects do not have a `save` method. You can `open` them and you can `write` to them but the idiom of "saving" is essentially opening, making changes, then writing back to the same file.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the insight. Do you have any idea on how I can save the image then?

Comment: The `TaskImages` object _does_ have a `save` method. You want to call `.save()` on it. for example: `TaskImages(UserTask=something, image=something_else).save()`. It seems you want to save a TaskImage to a database, not an image to a disk.

Comment: It seems I didn't fully understand you question before. You need to create a new TaskImage first. Ie `task_image = TaskImage()` then do the rest of your code. The issue is you are calling `.image` on the class `TaskImages` instead of an instance of that class `TaskImages()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer lead me to finding a solution.